# Graphql field is always null

Tags: database, postgresql, graphql, typeorm, typegraphql

Hey I try to access an foreign key value in my schema.

```
@ObjectType()
@Entity("Vehicle")
export class Vehicle extends BaseEntity {
  @Field(() => Int)
  @PrimaryColumn()
  id!: number;

  @Field(() => String)
  @Column({unique: true})
  serial_id!: String;

  @ManyToOne(() => Vehicle_Model, model => model.id)
  @JoinColumn({ name: 'model' })
  model!: Vehicle_Model;

  @OneToOne(() => Battery)
  @JoinColumn({ name: 'battery' })
  battery!: number;

  @ManyToOne(() => Operator, operator => operator.id)
  @JoinColumn({ name: 'operator' })
  @Field()
  operator: Operator;

  @Field(() => String)
  @CreateDateColumn()
  created: Date;
}
```

For example i want to access the operator field in my graphql-playground and the id which is in operator is my primary key of the Operator class.

```
@ObjectType()
@Entity()
export class Operator extends BaseEntity {
  @Field()
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id!: number;

  @Field(() => String)
  @Column({ unique: true })
  email!: string;

  @Column()
  password!: string;

  @Field(() => String)
  @CreateDateColumn()
  created: Date;
}
```

This is the Operator class.
Now when I try to access the operator field I get the following error:
"Cannot return null for non-nullable field Vehicle.operator."

I can get all the normal values like serial_id or created but not my foreign keys.

I hope anyone can help me :)

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The way you have defined `@ManyToOne` relationship should be changed like below:

```js
@ObjectType()
@Entity("Vehicle")
export class Vehicle extends BaseEntity {
  @ManyToOne(() => Operator)
  // '@JoinColumn' specifies which column in your 'Vehicle' entity contains the
  // foreign key to 'Operator' entity. It should not be equal to the name of the
  // relation. You can simply remove '@JoinColumn' or use a different name and
  // define that column in your entity like below
  @JoinColumn({ name: 'operatorId' })
  @Field()
  operator: Operator;

  @Column()
  operatorId: number;
}
```

You should check all your relationships because I see that they have also not defined accordingly.

I suggest you read [Many-to-one / one-to-many relations](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/master/docs/many-to-one-one-to-many-relations.md) and [One-to-one relations](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/master/docs/one-to-one-relations.md) documents before proceeding forward.

Further, if you're not joining `Vehicle` entity with `Operator` entity when querying, you should also look into [Eager and Lazy Relations](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/master/docs/eager-and-lazy-relations.md) document.

Hope this helps. Cheers  !!!